# Calculate NEO object position with nasa Near Earth Object data

Tags: positional-astronomy, celestial-mechanics, near-earth-object

I wish to create a 3D visualisation of NEO's by date in relation to earth, but calculating their position at that time has got me stuck.

From this question I was able to fine Nasa's NEO object data:

[Previous Question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/602/how-can-an-amateur-astronomer-verify-the-position-of-near-earth-objects)

Listing Of NEO's:

[Nasa Date range NEO Data](https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2015-09-07&end_date=2015-09-08&api_key=DEMO_KEY)

[Detailed NEO Data](https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/neo/3726710?api_key=DEMO_KEY)

Given the information in these JSON streams. Is it possible to calculate the position of the NEO in relation to earth? It doesn't seem to offer any positional information that I can see, although this is not my field.

Or is there a better data set which will assist me in this?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this on space.SE?

Comment: Yes he did https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23541/calculate-neo-object-position-with-nasa-near-earth-object-data No crossposting on SE sites please, Marc: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Aplogies I wasnt sure the best place, after posting in Space.SE this SE area seemed more viable

Comment: It's hard to resist the temptation to occasionally cross-post, especially when you really need an answer in a hurry, but I think the belief is that it would get quickly out of control if it weren't against the rules. Double check [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23546/12102) to see if it is what you are looking for or not, and let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you had linked as 'Detailed NEO Data' lists all the orbital parameters needed to determine the position of the object as a function of time. It lists these parameters for the objects orbiting the earth. This should be just what you need. They are located at bottom of file. There are routines to convert the orbit in orbital parameters to cartesian coordinates. This may be easier to use. You can google on orbital parameters conversion to find these routines. I think I have a copy in Fortran but not many people use Fortran now.